# Inheriting a Property vs setting the BindableAttribute

Tags: vb.net

There are man properties of the CONTROL class which are inherited by the FORM class. However there are some properties like LOCATION, TEXT etc. which as per the MSDN documentation are not inherited. rather what they mention is the

> The Location property gets or sets the Location property of the Control base class, and sets the Bindable property to true.

What is the meaning of this statement? Isnt inheriting an easy and simple thing to do? Can someone pls what is happening and why is it being done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the implementation of the `Form.Location` property:

```cs
/// <summary>
///  Gets or sets the location of the form.
/// </summary>
[SettingsBindable(true)]
public new Point Location
{
    get => base.Location;
    set => base.Location = value;
}
```

Basically, it acts as a passthrough for the `Control.Location` property, so it behaves as though it was inherited for the most part, but it also makes that property on forms more easily bindable via settings, where the base property on controls is not so easily bindable. The reason for this is that you normally don't move controls around and want to remember their location across sessions but doing so for forms is quite common, so the attribute is added to make it easy to do so via settings.

To see the result, create a form and add a control to it. Select the control, open the *Properties* window and expand the `(ApplicationSettings)` node. There you will see the `Text` property listed. Now do the same for the form itself and you will see the `Location` property listed along with `Text`. If you go into `(PropertyBinding)` then you can still bind `Location` for a control but the attribute makes it easier for a form because doing so is far more common for a form.